# Why MySQL keep writing the same value in INSERT query

Tags: php, android, mysql

I've been confuse for a long time to think what's wrong with my code..
MySQL keep writing and save it into the table with the same value when I try to INSERT a new value for specific column.

Here is my Table structure (reservation table):

```
reservation
-----------------
id_reservation  int(3)
no_seat1        varchar(4)
no_seat2        varchar(4)
no_account      int(13)
```

and here is my reservation.java code :

```
reservation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_reservation);

    reservation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_seat1", no_seat1.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_seat2", no_seat2.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_account", no_account.getText().toString()));

                String response = null;

                try {

                       response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/cinemainfo/reservation.php", postParameters);

                       String res = response.toString();

                       res = res.trim();

                       res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                       no_seat1.setText("");
                       no_seat2.setText("");
                       no_account.setText("");

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                 }
            }
        }
    });
```

and here is my php code (reservation.php) :

```
$no_seat1 = $_POST['no_seat1'];
$no_seat2 = $_POST['no_seat2'];
$no_account = $_POST['no_account'];

$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$query = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES ('','$no_seat1', '$no_seat2', '$no_account')";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("FAILED save data!");
```

When I run in emulator..it's fine, but the data that saved in my reservation table seems wrong.. For the first insert, the data for no_account is `2147483647` and I've never input that number..
so i tried the second insert and it still the same...the data that saved in no_account column is `2147483647` .. and i don't have any idea what's wrong with my code...

I really appreciate any help that you give to me..thank you :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be fair to assume that if a value (that isn't entered in the applications UI) is being saved, and saved repeatedly, the no_account.getText() might not be returning what you think it is ? Can you log the value prior to sending the request ? Also you say you've been confused about this for a while, could it be that you've been confused since 19th january as the value you mention is a timestamp to match that date ? ;)

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand on what you say :(

Comment: can you store other two data in correct way

Comment: Could try using the android log to log the values of :

no_seat1.getText().toString();
no_seat2.getText().toString();
no_account.getText().toString();

and verify if the values are correct BEFORE sending the data ?

Comment: @No_Rulz Yes I can..the other data (no_seat1 and no_seat2) are fine..

Comment: @IgorZinken tell me how to do it, Sir..? I really don't have any idea. thank you

Comment: @No_Rulz 4 columns and for the id_reservation is auto_increment

Comment: what is your response string value?

Comment: change your no_account datatype as varchar() orelse you need to convert string into integer while you're get from account_no edittext..

Comment: I think No_Rulz just hit the nail on the head, 2147483647 is the max value for an unsigned integer, can you confirm the database column type for account_no is varchar ? The reason why this would create an error is because you're trying to save a character sequence as a number, and in the conversion it exceeds the maximum allowed range.

Comment: @IgorZinken yes, Sir you're right..now I only have to change the data type for no_account to varchar.. thank you for your explanation :)

Comment: Thank No_rulz for the solution :)